# query is that it still displays duplicate dates, but different shift

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

can you help me to find the correct query.
I want to display employee shifting change data in 1 month.
here's my query, the problem in my query is that it still displays duplicate dates :

```
SELECT
  l.NIK, l.enroll, cs.idGroupShift
  FROM
  attandenceLog l LEFT JOIN transaksiChangeShift cs ON l.NIK = cs.NIK
  WHERE
  l.NIK=007 AND date(l.enroll) BETWEEN date(cs.dateStart) AND IFNULL(date(cs.dateEnd), date(cs.dateStart))
GROUP BY l.enroll, cs.idGroupShift
```

this is an example table

**changeShift table's**

| idx | NIK | dateStart | dateEnd | idShift |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | 23/10/2021 | 29/10/2021 | 3 |
| 2 | 001 | 24/10/2021 | 24/10/2021 | 1 |
| 3 | 001 | 27/10/2021 | 31/10/2021 | 5 |
| 4 | 001 | 26/10/2021 | 28/10/2021 | 2 |

**attandace table's**

| idx | NIK | enroll |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | 23/10/2021 |
| 2 | 001 | 24/10/2021 |
| 3 | 001 | 25/10/2021 |
| 4 | 001 | 26/10/2021 |
| 5 | 001 | 27/10/2021 |
| 6 | 001 | 28/10/2021 |
| 7 | 001 | 29/10/2021 |
| 8 | 001 | 30/10/2021 |
| 9 | 001 | 31/10/2021 |

***expected result table:***

| idx | NIK | enroll | idShift |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 | 23/10/2021 | 3 |
| 2 | 001 | 24/10/2021 | 1 |
| 3 | 001 | 25/10/2021 | 3 |
| 4 | 001 | 26/10/2021 | 2 |
| 5 | 001 | 27/10/2021 | 2 |
| 6 | 001 | 28/10/2021 | 2 |
| 7 | 001 | 29/10/2021 | 5 |
| 8 | 001 | 30/10/2021 | 5 |
| 9 | 001 | 31/10/2021 | 5 |

***please help me, i'm stuck***

Comment: Are those dates really stored as `DD/MM/YYYY` format? But it seems like your query is using `DATE()` function so a copy & paste formatting mistake, I guess? But if the actual dates in your table are stored as standard `DATE` format, why do you need to use `DATE()` function? You'll only use it if your column datatype is `DATETIME`.

Comment: The reason why you got duplicates is because your `changeShift` table have overlapping `dateStart` and `dateEnd`. For example, see `idx=2`, the date is `24/10/2021` which appear in between `dateStart` and `dateEnd` of `idx=1`. Your operation is doing `BETWEEN` then grouped with `..  l.enroll, cs.idGroupShift`. So any date appear in `l.enroll` that is between that will get returned twice or more. If `changeShift` data supposed to be like that, then which date should be returned if both `idGroupShift` appear on a certain `enroll`?